# Bing map- At higher zoom Level MapPolyline goes invisible

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, gps, bing

i am making a project in bing map.I have to show driving direction on bing map.
When i plot MapPolyline in bing map it is showing correctly in map,but as i increase the zoom level or as i am zooming IN. The mapPolyline goes inVisible.
Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It is not clear what you ask. Please read [FAQ] and [ask] as a start..

Comment: Which Bing Maps API are you using?